# Dynamic file upload in anugularjs

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, pdf.js, angular-file-upload

In my current project I need to edit a pdf document. I have implemented editing the pdf file (using canvas, fabricjs) now the challenge is to update the pdf file on the server with the edited pdf document. What am doing is:

1. Convert pdf to image
2. Edit image on canvas
3. Create pdf with edited images (using pdfjs)

In the 3rd step, all the images are in an array, and I generate an image for every item in array. These images are added to a pdf file and the pdf is successfully downloading but how do I update the file on the system with the edited document?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to rephrase your question a little so it is more easily readable.

Comment: 1. am getting a pdf file from server. 2.editing the pdf document. 3.downloading the edited document.  up to here i have no issues but i need to update the original pdf file on the server with the latest edited pdf document.

Comment: am generating a pdf file from an array of base64 images using jspdf. It is downloading perfectly but am unable to update the edited document to server.